# Trying to understand the role of super wildcard in Java Generics

Tags: java, generics, extends, super

I was going through [this](https://www.codejava.net/java-core/collections/generics-with-extends-and-super-wildcards-and-the-get-and-put-principle) article to understand the role of `super` wildcard in generics. I understood how `extends` works, but I am having difficulty understanding `super`

I have a `ClassA` that is **extended** by `ClassB`, making `ClassA` super class of `ClassB`.

If I understood the article correctly, the `<? super ClassB>` would allow any Class that is a super type of `ClassB`.

I have the following code

**GenericMethod.java**

```
public class GenericMethod<T> {

    private List<T> list;

    public GenericMethod() {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void add(T t) {
        list.add(t);
    }

    public T get(int index) {
        return list.get(index);
    }
}
```

**Driver.java**

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GenericMethod<? super ClassB> genericMethod = new GenericMethod<>();

        ClassA classA = new ClassA();
        genericMethod.add(classA); // Compile-time error here

    }

}
```

**Error**

`The method add(capture#1-of ? super ClassB) in the type GenericMethod<capture#1-of ? super ClassB> is not applicable for the arguments (ClassA)`

I don't understand where I am going wrong. When I instantiated the `GenericMethod` class, I already declared that it would accept any value that is a **super type** of `ClassB` with the declaration `<? super ClassB>`. Thus, the `T` inside the `GenericMethod` class should accept all classes that `ClassB` extends.

Why does the `add` method throw the compile-time error then? Shouldn't the method `add` already know that it's being passed a perfectly compatible type?

Answer (score 1):

The `? super` clause is a lower-bound wildcard.  But the bound is on the type parameter that is inferred, not a restriction on the types of arguments that can be passed to a method that takes a parameter of that generic type.

When you say `<? super ClassB>`, you indicate that the type parameter can be `ClassB` or any supertype, e.g. `ClassA` or `Object`.

The compiler must treat the `add` method as if it could be any of these signatures:

```
add(Object t)
add(ClassA t)
add(ClassB t)
```

(There could be other types if `ClassA` inherited directly from another class instead of `Object`).

The compiler must reject a `ClassA` as an argument to `add` because the type parameter could be inferred as `ClassB`.  It's legal to assign a `GenericMethod<ClassB>` to your `genericMethod` variable.

```
GenericMethod<? super ClassB> genericMethod = new GenericMethod<ClassB>();
```

But it doesn't make sense to be able to pass a `ClassA` to a method that expects a `ClassB`.

In fact that is what is inferred by the diamond operator - `ClassB`.

Your confusion is in the conflation of two concepts: what type parameters are allowed and what types of objects are allowed in methods that use a type parameter.  Using a wildcard restricts the type parameter, but the method still accepts types that are the type parameter or a subtype.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you meant by **The compiler must reject a ClassA as an argument to add because the type parameter could be inferred as ClassB**?

Comment: I am not understanding the point of using a lower-bound type parameter if the method in the class is going to accept only those that are of lower-bound class or subtype of that.

Comment: Please see [What is PECS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).  A method that takes a parameter typed as a generic type parameter, which is in turn defined with `? super` is guaranteed to be able to accept an argument typed as the lower bound or lower.  Here, the `add` method is only guaranteed to be able to accept an argument of type `ClassB` or lower, not matter what the actual type parameter is.

Answer (score 1):

By declaring `GenericMethod<? super ClassB>` you are declaring the type is an unknown type that is a super-class of ClassB (or ClassB itself). And asking the compiler to only allow subtypes of this unknown type to be added to the list.

The only compatible subtypes the compiler knows are ClassB and any subtypes of ClassB. When creating instances, it is usually better to avoid wildcards.

For method parameters, wildcards give you more flexibility on what can be accepted. Use `PECS` (producer=extends, consumer=super) to determine which to use.
[See Slide 5](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/ts-5217-159242.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I admit that it is a bit counterintuitive, but from the point of view of the compiler, it makes sense.

Suppose you define a list in this way:

```
List<? super ClassB> myList;
```

And you got

```
ClassB extends ClassA;
ClassC extends ClassA;
```

Could you do ?

```
ClassA a = new ClassC();
myList.add (a);//does not compile
```

No, by several reasons. First because finally, at runtime, the parametrized type becomes a **concrete** and **single** type. So, in practice you **cannot mix** ClassA objects with ClassB objects.

And second, because the compiler **must check** that whatever **you insert is casteable** to **ClassB**. So, only adding a ClassB object (or a subtype of him), fulfil the contract. **But the opposite is not always true!** A ClassA object could no be a super type of ClassB.

> I.e. the object "a" is actually a ClassC object!

That is why  you cannot add a supertype. So it only lets you add ClassB objects -or subtypes-

If you cast the object "a" to ClassB, would be compile, but will fail at runtime getting a *ClassCastException*:

```
ClassA a = new ClassC();
myList.add((ClassB) a); //Compiles but fails at runtime
```

At the same time, the wildcard combined with super, can be used as a formal parameter of a method. I.e.:

```
void printValues (List<? super ClassB> list)
```

This way permits generelize the treatment of super ClassB collections, making possible this calls:

```
List<Object> lo;
List<ClassA> la;
...
printValues (lo);
printValues (la);
```

In this case, the definition using wildcards like <? super ClassB>, makes a little more sense.